# Escaping special character in Hibernate select query with fts

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am having the query like these

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("select object from EntityObject object where lower(object.columnName) like lower (E'%\\(test\\)%')");
```

and

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select object from EntityObject object where fts('english',contact.searchColumn,'testing (test)') = true;
```

I am trying to escape the special characters in the search text with the backslash and I am using postgres 8.3 with standard_conforming_strings in on state. By using "E" I am getting error as

> unexpected token: '%\(test\)%' near line 1 for the first case

and getting below error for the next case

> ERROR: syntax error in tsquery: "testing (test)"

Please help me to solve this problem. My intention is to escape special character especially parentheses "()" with backslash.

Comment: Why is your like clause having an "E" outside the single quotes?

Comment: I tried to escape special character as it is specified here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS
"Escape string syntax should be used if an application desires backslashes to be treated as escape characters."

Comment: Did you try using Restrictions?

Comment: No I didn't tried using Restrictions I wanted to do it in this method.

Comment: I think you need to 'set standard_conforming_strings=on' in your postgresql database. But I doubt you can do it programmatically

Comment: but is there a way to make backslashes as a escape character with 'standard_conforming_string = on' in code

Comment: tbh i have not seen any mate. Could you check the possibility of using the concatenation (||) and the chr function. For "(" it would be 40 and ")" it would be 41.
check this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 3):

The function `lower` is expecting a string as the parameter. `E'%\\(test\\)%'` is not a valid string because there is no single `'` at the beginning. `'E%\\(test\\)%'` would be a correct string - thought I wonder what you want to do with that, it is not correct escaping in HQL neither in SQL.

In the `like` statement there are only two special wildcard characters, `_` and `%`. If you want to escape them, you have to define an escape character.

Example: Select all rows whose name begins with an underscrore `_`

```
from YourTable where name like '!_%' escape '!'
```

And if you want to escape the `'` anywhere in SQL (not only the `like` statement), then you have to enter it twice.

Example: Select the row which name is `Peter's`

```
from YourTable where name = 'Peter''s'
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to escape parentheses "() " for that i tried to append it with backslashes and then i want to escape special characters in that string.And your code  "from YourTable where name like '!_%' escape '!'" - is not fetching result for me.

Comment: You do not need to escape parentheses. They do not have any special meaning in the HQL `like` statement.

Comment: yes thank you for like we don't need to escape parentheses but in tsquery('english', 'testing (test)')=true we need right? Can u tell me the way to do it in ts_query?

Comment: `tsquery` is a Postgresql speciality. It is neither HQL nor standard SQL. Might be it does not work when using in an HQL statement. Use `createSqlQuery()` instead of createQuery(), there you can use exactly the syntax as you would do in SQL. You'll loose the portability to other databases then, but that anyway is the case when using tsquery.